# XPATH - Ignore 1 page element, grab the rest

Tags: xpath

I can't seem to figure this out due to the square brackets issue. I have an html page full of h3 tags with `hrefs` that I need to grab but one has a class on that I don't want. Example:

I want all `H3`s `hrefs` but not this one:

```
<h3 class="leave_this"><a href="test">Leave me alone!</a>
```

To grab all the `hrefs` I am using this:

```
//h3/a/@href
```

Tried a few variations but no luck.

*REMOVED CONFUSING EXAMPLE, APOLOGIES*

Comment: Please clean this up. 1) Why is the class name different? 2) Why do you need this if you also test for an `id`? They are supposed to be unique.

Comment: That was an example, apologies for confusion. Removed. @reinierpost

Comment: `//h3[not(@class="leave_this")]/a/@href`?